# PowerShell failing to copy from UNC path

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to copy a folder from a UNC path to a local server. I'm remotely running my script through an interactive session and utilizing Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer -ScriptBlock $Script
```

This is the script to do the copying:

```
$script {
try {

New-PSDrive -Name MyDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\uncpathserver\e$\SourceCode\ -Credential Contoso\me

Copy-Item -Path \\uncpathserver\e$\SourceCode\* -Destination E:\Inetpub\Target -Recurse -Force
}
catch {
Write-Host "Failed to copy!"
}
}
```

It is failing and throwing my catch block every time. I can't seem to figure out what I am missing to get this to work - it seems so simple and I hope I'm not missing something blatantly obvious.

EDIT:

I was able to get it to work by now just running the script from my local PC instead of from a server. I'm calling the file copy out of $script block now as well. This is what the new code looks like:

```
$MyServers= @("server-01", "server-02")

foreach ($server in $MyServers)

{
  $TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential 
  contoso\me
  Copy-Item -ToSession $TargetSession -Path C:\Source\TheCode\ -
  Destination "E:\InetPub\wherethecodegoes" -Recurse -Force

  }
```

Everything else I'm doing inside my $script block (which has been omitted here for troubleshooting sake) is working A-OK. I do have to enter my credentials for each server, but due to the small nature of servers I'm working with, that isn't a deal breaker.

Comment: remove the catch block so you can see what the error is.

Comment: Cannot find path \\uncpathserver\e$\SourceCode\ because it does not 
exist is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Have you tried a `net use` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a '*kerberos double hop*' problem.

**Short-Answer**

Avoid the problem. From your system, setup *two* PSdrives. Then copy `\\uncpathserver\e$\SourceCode\` to `\\RemoteIISserver\E$\Inetpub\Target\`

**Long-Answer**

From your system (System A), you are remotely executing a script (on System B) that will copy a remote folder (from System C).

It should work, but it doesn't. This is because when you (specifically, your account) from `System A`, remotely connects to `System B`, then asks `System C` for something, 'System C' doesn't trust you.

A quick google of the problem will show a myriad of ways around this issue, however;

- Not all methods are secure (example: CredSSP)
- Not all methods will work on your version of Windows (which is...?)
- Not all methods will work with PowerShell

One [secure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/) method that does work with PowerShell leverages delegation.
This can be a bit daunting to setup, and I suggest you read-up on this thoroughly.

```
## Module 'ActiveDirectory' from RSAT-AD-PowerShell Windows feature required.
$ServerA = $Dnv:COMPUTERNAME            
$ServerB = Get-ADComputer -Identity ServerB            
$ServerC = Get-ADComputer -Identity ServerC
```

Delegate 'Server B' to access 'Server C';

```
# Set the resource-based Kerberos constrained delegation 
Set-ADComputer -Identity $ServerC -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount $ServerB

# Confirm AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity.Access is correct (indirectly).
Get-ADComputer -Identity $ServerC -Properties PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount
```

Wait about 15 minutes for 'Server B' to sync-up (or just reboot it).
You can force this with the following (Note: `$Cred` should contain your credentials);

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerB.Name -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {            
    klist purge -li 0x3e7            
}
```

Run a test-hop;

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerB.Name -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
  Test-Path \\$($using:ServerC.Name)\C$
  Get-Process lsass -ComputerName $($using:ServerC.Name)
  Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 3 -ComputerName $($using:ServerC.Name)
}
```

The downside is you have to setup every remote remote-target (every 'Server C') this way. But the upside is that it's secure.